# Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: Object

Tags: c#, vb.net, uipath

datatable.Compute("Sum([My Money])","");
Error: Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: Object.

Comment: What is the data type of that column?

Comment: Hi, it seem to be Double, but I dont know exactly.
4,124,175.00 /
307,447.00/ 
300,000.00/
6,700,000.00/
3,005,000.00/

Comment: It doesn't matter what it seems to be. It matters what it is. If you don't know, look.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm very new. This data I got from an excel file. Do you get any Idea to fix this.

Comment: It "seems" to be a double, but does it have the commas in too ? (So it's a string then)

Comment: To find the type of a DataTable column `Dim typeName = dt.Columns("My Money").DataType.Name`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable

With table.Columns
    .Add("Integers", GetType(Integer))
    .Add("Objects", GetType(Object))
End With

With table.Rows
    .Add(1, 1)
    .Add(2, 2)
    .Add(3, 3)
End With

Dim integerSum = CInt(table.Compute("SUM(Integers)", Nothing))
Dim objectSum = CInt(table.Compute("SUM(Objects)", Nothing))
```

If you run that code, guess what happens. The first `Compute` call works and the second throws an exception with the same error message you report. The issue is exactly what the error message suggests it is: you're trying to sum data of a type that can't logically be summed.

If you want to be able to sum numbers then you need to make sure that you have numbers to sum. I don't know how you created your `DataTable` and its columns in the first place because you didn't show us but you need to make sure that you do it such that your numerical data is stored in a column with the appropriate numerical data type.